# how to have domain without www and MX records work together?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, mx-record, cname-record

I think i have a common problem but wasn't able to find much resources for answering it. We have a domain and it works when we resolve it as www.domain.com, i have also setup a MX record pointing @ to mx.mailserver.com, this ensures that emails send to whatever@domain.com are sent to the mx record. However i notice that with this configuration the subdomain domain.com (without WWW) fails to resolve. We are using namecheap as the DNS provider, Strikingly as the host and zoho as the mail server..

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Have you tried just adding the address records you want?

Answer (score 2):

You need to repeat for domain.com the A RR you have for www.domain.com, in addition to the MX RR, like this:

```
$ORIGIN example.com.
@      IN MX 10 mail.mailprovider.com.
       IN A     192.0.2.80
www    IN A     192.0.2.80
```

Answer (score 0):

You do need to add a separate record for each cname you want. Www remote sub domain etc, otherwise it has no IP address to finally resolve to.